# To build an image URL using XMLHttpRequest for TMDB?

Tags: javascript, api, themoviedb-api

How can I build a URL and then get a particular poster of movie using javascript. I went through documentation of TMDB here -> https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/movies/get-movie-images and  https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/configuration/get-api-configuration but as I am new to API's the documentation is so confusing. Basically I am trying to replicate this ->https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/02/beginners-guide-jquery-based-json-api-clients/ with pure Javascript.

```
<body>
<img id="movie-poster" src="">

<input id="movie_title" type="text" name="Enter Movie title" value="Please Enter">
<input type="submit" name="Submit">

<script type="text/javascript">
    var getposter = function () {

        var film = document.getElementById("movie_title").value;

        if(film == ''){
            document.write("<h2> We haven't forgotten  to validate the form! Please enter something. </h2>")
        } else {

            document.write("Loading your poster <br>");

            var data = "{}";

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.withCredentials = true;

            xhr.addEventListener("movie-poster", function () {
                 if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
                      console.log(this.responseText);
                     }
            });

            xhr.open("GET", "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/%7Bmovie_id%7D/images?language=en-US&api_key=%3C%3Capi_key%3E%3E");

            xhr.send(data);
        }
    }
</script>
```